# How to make a text center top and other text center of screen in LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have two `textviews`. I want to make a `textview` center of top which can be used as title of application. And the second `textview` is center of screen which used to show detail. I am use `ScrollView` and `LinearLayout` as below setting. However, it does not work for second `textview`. Could you see my layout file and give me the way to solve it? I need to use `ScrollView` and `LinearLayout`, because I don't want to modify the java code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_app"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Main title-Center-top"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/display"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="I want to center of screen"
            />

    </LinearLayout>    
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This is unnecessary complication. I would suggest you put the time and make it a `RelativeLayout` inside the `ScrollView`. Also, this time when you code in java don't typecast to `LinearLayout` but to `ViewGroup`. This will reduce dependency. Always remember to `Code for interface and not implementation`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout 
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical">
         <LinearLayout
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_weight="0"
                  android:orientation="horizontal">
         <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/title_app"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="50dp"
                 android:text="Main title-Center-top"
                 android:layout_gravity="center"
                 android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                 android:textSize="20sp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/display"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="I want to center of screen"
            />
     </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What does not work the second textview still remain at top or what??

Comment: Yes. It does not go to center of screen.

Comment: Have you added `android:fillViewport="true"` as Dhaval suggested with my xml code

Comment: Thank . I added android:fillViewport="true" and it work now.

Answer (score 1):

This is the full `xml` code that should do what you want, I just tested it and works:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_app"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Main title-Center-top"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="I want to center of screen"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks okay to me.

Just put **`android:fillViewport="true" on the ScrollView`**

Your problem seems like ScrollView is not stretching to its full height.

Comment: I put it but second textview still not center of screen

Comment: Instead of fix height android:layout_height="50dp" use  android:layout_height="match_parent". for the second textview.